# Hosted continuous integration for R?

Tags: r, continuous-integration

I have looked at some hosted CI providers, but no one promised to actually support R out of the box. Ideally, one could specify different versions of R to test the code with. I'm interested in the automatic testing and building of open-source R packages.

So: If there is such a provider with good support for R -- where? If not, with which provider will the setup be least painless?

Comment: FYI - This will attract lots of close votes because you're basically asking for a recommendation for such a provider, which is generally not a sort of question SO encourages.

Comment: @joran: Thank you. Well... How to reformat the question then?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure if that will be possible. This would generally be referred to as a "shopping" question (as in, you're shopping for a provider and asking for recommendations). And I don't often see those sorts of things reworked into something constructive. Perhaps someone else has some ideas, though.

Comment: @krlmlr maybe you can use `gradle`. It seems it has an [R plugin](http://wiki.gradle.org/display/GRADLE/Plugins#Plugins-RPlugin). I am not sure since I haven't use this plugin.

Comment: I voted to close, although I think I should have said "too localized", since in a year's time who knows what CI providers might there be for R. Its too fluid a situation, which isn't what SO is all about.

Comment: I'm a founder of https://CircleCI.com. Give it a shot and talk to us over support, and we'll get it working.

Comment: This question now has an answer: https://github.com/craigcitro/r-travis